# Simple-Kafka-consumer message delivery duplication

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to implement a simple Producer-->Kafka-->Consumer application in Java. I am able to produce as well as consume the messages successfully, but the problem occurs when I restart the consumer, wherein some of the already consumed messages are again getting picked up by consumer from Kafka (not all messages, but a few of the last consumed messages).

I have set `autooffset.reset=largest` in my consumer and my `autocommit.interval.ms` property is set to 1000 milliseconds.

Is this 'redelivery of some already consumed messages' a known problem, or is there any other settings that I am missing here?

Basically, is there a way to ensure none of the previously consumed messages are getting picked up/consumed by the consumer?

Answer (score 3):

Kafka uses Zookeeper to store consumer offsets. Since Zookeeper operations are pretty slow, it's not advisable to commit offset after consumption of every message.

It's possible to add shutdown hook to consumer that will manually commit topic offset before exit. However, this won't help in certain situations (like jvm crash or `kill -9`). To guard againts that situations, I'd advise implementing custom commit logic that will commit offset locally after processing each message (file or local database), and also commit offset to Zookeeper every 1000ms. Upon consumer startup, both these locations should be queried, and maximum of two values should be used as consumption offset.

Comment: it might sound stupid but if we say for example implement the custom commit logic then is it possible to manage the offset for every message. For example if I have two message with a timestamp value in it then I would like to set the offset based on the timestamp. So if the second record is having a earlier timestamp then the offset assign to it should be less than the other. So while consuming I will receive messages which are already sorted.